# How to get all direct children of a BeautifulSoup Tag?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, siblings

How to retrieve (not recursively) all children using BeautifulSoup (bs4) ?

`<div class='body'><span>A</span><span><span>B</span></span><span>C</span></div>`

I want to get blocks like this :

```
block1 : <span>A</span>
block2 : <span><span>B</span></span>
block3 : <span>C</span>
```

I'm doing this way :

```
for j in soup.find_all(True)[:1]:
            if isinstance(j, NavigableString):
                continue
            if isinstance(j, Tag):
                tags.append(j.name)
                # Get siblings
                for k in j.find_next_siblings():
                    # k is sibling of first element
```

Is there a cleaner way to do that?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can set the [`recursive`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument) argument to `False` if you want to select only direct descendants.
An example with the html you provided:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = "<div class='body'><span>A</span><span><span>B</span></span><span>C</span></div>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml") 
for j in soup.div.find_all(recursive=False):
    print(j)
```

---

```
<span>A</span>
<span><span>B</span></span>
<span>C</span>
```